# SwiftUI: EditButton says "Done" after swipe to delete action

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Why does the EditButton says "Done" (instead of "Edit") after I delete one scrum using "swipe to delete"?

I tried changing editMode to .inactive inside onDelete, but even this didn't work.

Why is this not working, and can I fix it somehow?
Is it some new bug?

```
struct ScrumsView: View {
    @Binding var scrums: [DailyScrum]
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @State private var isPresentingNewScrumView = false
    @State private var newScrumData = DailyScrum.Data()
    let saveAction: ()->Void
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($scrums) { $scrum in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(scrum: $scrum)) {
                    CardView(scrum: scrum)
                }
                .listRowBackground(scrum.theme.mainColor)
            }
            .onDelete { indexSet in
                scrums.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Daily Scrums")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                EditButton()
            }
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    isPresentingNewScrumView = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                .accessibilityLabel("New scrum")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingNewScrumView) {
            NavigationView {
                DetailEditView(data: $newScrumData)
                    //.navigationTitle(Text("New Scrum"))
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                            Button("Dismiss") {
                                isPresentingNewScrumView = false
                                newScrumData = DailyScrum.Data()
                            }
                        }
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                            Button("Add") {
                                let newScrum = DailyScrum(data: newScrumData)
                                scrums.append(newScrum)
                                isPresentingNewScrumView = false
                                newScrumData = DailyScrum.Data()
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            if phase == .inactive { saveAction() }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `EditButton` is incompatible with this new way of using `@StateObject` to declare the store object. I had the idea to try reverting to the old way of creating the store object and surprisingly it fixed the issue. Change the `ScrumStore` to this

```
class ScrumStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var scrums: [DailyScrum] = []
    
    static var shared = ScrumStore()
```

And change the `ScrumdingerApp` to this:

```
struct ScrumdingerApp: App {
    private var store = ScrumStore.shared
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ScrumsView(store: store) {
```

And `ScrumsView` to this:

```
struct ScrumsView: View {
    //@Binding var scrums: [DailyScrum]
    @ObservedObject var store: ScrumStore

...

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach($store.scrums) { $scrum in
```

And change the other `scrums` to `store.scrums` too.

This makes the edit button work properly for swipe to delete

I would also improve the code by making the store object be an Environment object, e.g.

```
struct ScrumdingerApp: App {
    private var store = ScrumStore.shared
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .environmentObject(store)
        }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: ScrumStore
   
...
```

I would also improve how the model structs are loaded and saved, e.g. I would load it in the object's init and have a function to save it. The function could be called on a scene phase or after the model is mutated. Before doing too much loading and saving you might want to try `FileDocument` which does all that for you and gives you iCloud drive support for free. I recommend the document app WWDC videos to learn that, there is a new one every year.

Comment: Thank you! I would NOT expect this to cause problem with EditButton. Especially in Apple's own tutorials! BTW You got me interested by saying, that you would also improve how the model is loaded and saved, because, since it's "Apple Tutorial", I was happy, that I learned how to do persistence "the right way". :-D Could you provide some clues on that?

Comment: Thank you for extending your answer! It helps a lot. It still confuses me, though, why Apple Engineers in all Apple WWDC videos, **ALWAYS** mark store with `@StateObject`, like here at 30:50 min: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/, or here at 44:30 min:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10119
Because indeed the EditButton always stops working when I add @StateObject before my store var. So why are they doing that? Why are they marking theirs store with `@StateObject` and everything works fine for them? I would be glad if you could answer :-)

Comment: Really great you shared those videos and timestamps! Apple really do think `@StateObject` should work in the App struct. The way I did it in my answer is the way we had to do it before `@StateObject` was added to SwiftUI. I would guess what has gone wrong is `@StateObject` was originally designed to work in a View that is accessing the object and perhaps EditButton is also expecting things to be done the old way. `@StateObject` declared in the App but no properties are accessed in the body seems pointless for body to be being called when the object changes and maybe EditButton is breaking.

Comment: Sorry for my vague comment, I'll keep investigating and see if I can figure this out and hopefully submit a bug to Apple.

Comment: I have found the workaround!: Inside ScrumsView, I added `@Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode` and inside `.onDelete` closure (at the end) this line: `editMode?.wrappedValue = .transient`. It's weird, but it's working to fix EditButton being stuck on "Done". It would be great If you would submit a bug to Apple, because you are more experienced than I am :-D And if Apple provides some tracking number for bug tracking, please share it (or keep me updated on the progress ;-)).

Comment: Great! That makes me think maybe the previous environment variables are all lost  when the scrum is deleted and`@StateObject` results in body being called in `ScrumdingerApp` and it creates a new `ScrumsView`.

Comment: Another way to fix it is put `@State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive` in `ScrumdingerApp` and in the body put `ScrumsView(){ ... }.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)`. This way it passes in the same `editMode` binding into `ScrumsView`'s environment every time.

Comment: Yes, this also works. Anyway, it's still a bug. 
Did you submit this bug to Apple, or should I submit?